# android package - R.attr nested class -- employing an api key

Tags: r, httr

I trying to imitate a CURL request using the HTTR package in R. It's for propbulica's election API.

propublica.github.io/campaign-finance-api-docs/

The command line request is documented as follows:

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json" -H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
```

My imitation of this in using R is as follows:

```
require(httr)
api_key <- "my key"
path <- "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json"
data <- GET(path, add_headers("X-API-Key", .headers = api_key))
content(data)
```

This returns a "forbidden".

Derek Willis, at ProPublica tells me my key is valid.

Comment: You might also see if the Rpublica package, on CRAN, covers this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the `curlconverter` package to help with just this sort of thing:

```
library(curlconverter)

cmd <- 'curl "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json" -H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"'

parsed_cmd <- straighten(cmd)

str(parsed_cmd)
## List of 1
##  $ :List of 5
##   ..$ url      : chr "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json"
##   ..$ method   : chr "get"
##   ..$ headers  :List of 1
##   .. ..$ X-API-Key: chr "PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
##   ..$ url_parts:List of 9
##   .. ..$ scheme  : chr "https"
##   .. ..$ hostname: chr "api.propublica.org"
##   .. ..$ port    : NULL
##   .. ..$ path    : chr "campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json"
##   .. ..$ query   : NULL
##   .. ..$ params  : NULL
##   .. ..$ fragment: NULL
##   .. ..$ username: NULL
##   .. ..$ password: NULL
##   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "url" "list"
##   ..$ orig_curl: chr "curl \"https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json\" -H \"X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY\""
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cc_obj" "list"
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cc_container" "list"

actual_function <- make_req(parsed_cmd)[[1]] # returns a list as it's vectorized
```

make the call - it should “just work”

```
# actual_function()  # not going to work here since it's not a real api key
```

see what’s inside:

```
actual_function
## function () 
## httr::VERB(verb = "GET", url = "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/president/totals.json",
##     httr::add_headers(`X-API-Key` = "PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"))
## <environment: 0x7f8d90aeee98>
```

It's designed to work with "Copy as cURL" strings from browser Developer Tools windows.

Comment: This is awesome! I've been wrestling with RCurl, httr, etc. and looking for this exact thing.

Comment: It's _heavily_ geared towards processing "Copy as cURL" URLs but if it needs more generalization, just file a PR :-)

Comment: Thanks very much @hrbrmstr. This has done the trick. Most brilliant. Will ask propublica to add this to their documentation.

Comment: except that there's already an R package to work with the ProPublica API :-) https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RPublica/RPublica.pdf

Comment: package ‘curlconverter’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)

Comment: It's in GitHub - devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/curlconverter")

Answer (score 0):

```
GET(path, config = list(token = api_key))
```

This is assuming "my key" is an oauth token environment. Would need to know more about the API to be sure. See the github examples in httr for key generation and api handshakes.