# R convert python GET to R http GET

Tags: python, r, get, httr

I'm trying to convert a working python program that retrieves information from a website with an api key to its R equivalent. Since I don't know much about httr or python it's a challenge. The python code is (somewhat abbreviated and with a dummy X-ApiKey)

```
url = 'https://api.clarivate.com/api/woslite'
query = 'ts=((land AND ocean AND climate AND change)) AND PY=2013-2019'
count = 100
firstRecord = 1
parameters = {'databaseId': 'WOK', 'usrQuery': query, 'count': count, 'firstRecord': firstRecord}
headers={'accept':'application/json','X-ApiKey':'********'}
 response = requests.get(url,params=parameters, headers=headers)
```

My attempt at an R version is

```
library(httr)
wosliteKey <- Sys.getenv("wosliteKey")

firstRecord <- 1
count <- 100
url <- 'https://api.clarivate.com/api/woslite'
query <- 'ts=(land AND ocean AND climate AND change) AND PY=2013-2019'

r <- GET(url, query = list(api_key = wosliteKey, usrQuery = query, databaseId = 'WOK', count = count, firstRecord = firstRecord))
```

Running the above returns

```
Response [https://api.clarivate.com/api/woslite]
  Date: 2019-05-09 22:50
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 41 B
```

status 401 means unauthorized access. The python code uses `X-ApiKey` rather than `api_key`. But I can't figure out a. what the difference is and b. how to put it into the query list.

Comment: Is there a login needed to access the api aside from the key? Usually this means that you are not authenticated correctly and need to pass in variables authenticate, usually a username/password.

Comment: Nope. No username or password needed. I didn't write the python code but it came with this comment - `#header includes authentication X-ApiKey specific to this API and user`

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the comments above I figured out how to make this work. The python version of httr GET looks like the following

```
response = requests.get(url,params=parameters, headers=headers)
```

For my problem, I have the following from the python program

```
parameters = {'databaseId': 'WOK', 'usrQuery': query, 'count': count, 'firstRecord': firstRecord}
headers={'accept':'application/json','X-ApiKey':'********'}
```

The equivalent with httr GET is

```
response <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(accept = 'application/json', `X-APIKey` = wosliteKey), query = list(databaseId = 'WOK', usrQuery = query, count = count, firstRecord = firstRecord))
```

The python headers info is replaced by the add_headers function from httr. The python parameters info is added as a list in the query option.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a while, i found something looks working with your problem.

[android package - R.attr nested class -- employing an api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630427/android-package-r-attr-nested-class-employing-an-api-key)